# How can I find a value, see if is equal to another and print the values of is row vba

Tags: arrays, vba, range

I'm new at VBA and I need help to do cycle that look for unique key and copy the values of is column, in different files. I will show you an example.

this is file one, where I have all data.

[image]

And this is the file 2 where I just have de headers.

[image]

I need to copy the values from file 1 to file that match with the unique key "CHAVE_UNICA".

How can I do this? thanks

Comment: No vba needed, VLOOKUP will do it.

Comment: Or in VBA, `Application.Match()`  or `Find()`